# Javascript syntax error ) SyntaxError Uncaught

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<li class="list-item regOptions">
      <a  onclick="EditRegPost('5' , 'I'M NEW REGULATION')">
            <span class="far fa-edit pr-1"></span>
            <span>Edit this post</span>
            <p class="text-muted">This will Update the content of this post</p>
     </a>
 </li>
```

this is how the syntax looks like on the browser

```
<li class="list-item regOptions">
    <a  onclick="EditRegPost(\'' . $row['id'] . '\' , \'' . $row['title'] . '\')">
         <span class="far fa-edit pr-1"></span>
          <span>Edit this post</span>
          <p class="text-muted">This will Update the content of this post</p>
   </a>
</li>
```

**and this is the syntax on the editor**
when I'm trying to invoke EditRegPost() function on click
it fails and display this message :
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
I'm not really sure how , my syntax seems to be right . I would appreciate any help , thanks

Comment: Take a careful look at the arguments in `onclick="EditRegPost('5' , 'I'M NEW REGULATION')"`. The quoting is messed up.

Comment: that's right my retrieved data is dismissing the thing at the  I'M quote  , I solved that like this  onclick="EditRegPost(\'' . $row['id'] . '\' , \'' . mysqli_real_escape_string($link , $row['title']) . '\')"

Answer (score 0):

Use \ in the String of the second param

`onclick="EditRegPost('5' , 'I\'M NEW REGULATION')"`

Comment: And how do you propose that this be done on dynamic data? The real code inserts a variable `$row['title']`, not the literal string (that's just browser output).

Comment: @El_Vanja Nobody can suggest a fix, since based on the question, we've no clue how `$row['title']` gets its value (there's a hint in a comment, though).

Comment: In this case I would do it with `str_replace('\'', '\\', $row['title]);`

Comment: thank you fellas , however that's right my retrieved data is dismissing the thing at the I'M quote , I solved that like this onclick="EditRegPost(\'' . $row['id'] . '\' , \'' . mysqli_real_escape_string($link , $row['title']) . '\')"

Comment: @Teemu My point was that the answerer had missed the point - the fix cannot be applied to literal data.

Comment: A better way would also be [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) because it's a string which looks like, it's displayed to the user and it will displayed correctly in HTML Elements